# Find the probability distribution for the smallest of three numbers

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Three positive numbers are selected at random(without replacement) from first six positive numbers. If X denotes the smallest of the three numbers obtained. Find the probability distribution of X. Also find the mean and variance.

I have tried solving the question by making a sample space and calculating the probability but that method is taking too long, is there any method to solve this question faster?

Comment: Hint:  compute $P(X≥i)$ for $i\in \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.

Comment: First six positive numbers?  Is $\Bbb R_+$ countable?

Comment: To explain @lulu's hint (which is MUCH preferable to the suggestions in the two currently not deleted answers), note that the event $[X\geqslant i]$ corresponds to choosing three numbers in $\{i,i+1,\ldots,6\}$, a set with $7-i$ elements hence $$P(X\geqslant i)=\frac{{7-i\choose 3}}{{6\choose 3}}=\frac{(7-i)(6-i)(5-i)}{6\cdot5\cdot4}$$ Next, use $$E(X)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty P(X\geqslant i)$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint

- There are ${6 \choose 3}=20$ equally probable ways of choosing the three numbers
- Of these, there are ${6-n \choose 2}$ ways of choosing the three numbers so the smallest is $n$ and the other two are in $n+1,n+2,\ldots, 6$
- Division will give probabilities $P_n$ for $n=1,2,3,4$
- The mean is $\sum(nP_n)$ and the variance is $\sum(n^2P_n)-(\sum(nP_n))^2$

Comment: I'm getting 120 ways of choosing three numbers and i did not understand what you did there. I'm only in 12th grade is there any other way to explain me what u did there

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing any stats, you can simply:

- evaluate the 120 possible permutations of 3 numbers from $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$
- then record the Min of each permutation, and
- then Tally the number of 1's, the number of 2s, the number of 3's and the number of 4's.

Here is *Mathematica* code that calculates the exact pmf in less than $\frac{1}{1000}$th of a second:

```
Map[Min, Permutations[Range[6], {3}]] // Tally
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 60 \\
 2 & 36 \\
 3 & 18 \\
 4 & 6 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

i.e. $P(X=1) = \frac{60}{120} = \frac12$,  $\quad P(X=2) = \frac{36}{120} \quad $ etc

There won't be any 5's or 6's, because in a sample of size 3, there will always be a number smaller than 5 or 6.